# Why is my python subprocess standard output empty?

Tags: python, python-3.x, subprocess

When these lines are executed in my Python script:

```
a = ['python', '-v']
finishedProcess = subprocess.run(a, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT, shell=True)
```

both `finishedProcess.stdout` and `finishedProcess.stderr` are empty, and `finishedProcess.returncode` is 0.  As you can see, I am even combining both stderr and stdout into the stdout variable.

I can run the same command directly from the command line and get output.

I have been following the directions from this posting: [Running shell command and capturing the output](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4760215/running-shell-command-and-capturing-the-output)

What am I doing wrong here?  My Python version is 3.7.6.

Comment: Edit:  I got rid of `shell=True` and now it works, but I don't understand why it works.  After reading the docs, I still don't really get what the shell option does.

Comment: Just ran the code on Win10 with Python 3.7.7 and got output in both cases (`shell=True` and `shell=False`). May it be environment specific issue?

Comment: Yep, seems that way.  Will need to keep debugging it.  It's good to hear that it should work both ways though.

Comment: Any more on this issue? I am facing the same and I keep getting None out of stdout, while I am sure there is some output.